# Link will not work with code sample?

Tags: discussion

I have found that if we have a link that is also formatted as `Code Sample` then the link will not work. Example, `[link][1]`

Comment: Why do you want the link to be inside of a code sample?  If you want users to be able to browse to the link, then it is a link not code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a code block, besides visual appearance, is to make sure that code isn't accidentally parsed as Markdown. Otherwise it would be unclear to readers what the actual code is.

If you're trying to make the link text look like code, try it like this:

```
[see the `FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)
```

> [see the `FooBar` documentation](http://www.example.com)